# How do you collect the results of a comprehension into an array in CoffeeScript?

Tags: coffeescript, list-comprehension

Instead of invoking a function on each matching value, I'd like get the array of values `['broccoli', 'spinach']`, but I keep getting compiler errors.  Could someone explain what I'm misunderstanding?

```
# Health conscious meal.  - This example is from http://coffeescript.org/#loops
foods = ['broccoli', 'spinach', 'chocolate']
eat food for food in foods when food isnt 'chocolate'

# Failed Attempt #1 - Unexpected TERMINATOR
arr = for food in foods when food isnt 'chocolate'

# Failed Attempt #2 - Unexpected ')'
arr = (for food in foods when food isnt 'chocolate')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing the value that the comprehension is supposed to return (which is `eat food` in the original, but you want to return `food` unmodified). So instead of:

```
for food in foods when food isnt 'chocolate'
```

You want:

```
food for food in foods when food isnt 'chocolate'
```

(Though if you're targeting modern JavaScript implementations, it would probably be more readable just to use something like `foods.filter (food) -> food isnt 'chocolate'`.)

Comment: Thanks, `arr = (food for food in foods when food isnt 'chocolate')` works.  The parentheses are necessary.

Comment: @davidzarlengo: Yeah, sorry, guess I should have mentioned that. Parens are usually necessary with comprehensions. Without the parens, the parser reads it as `((arr = food) for food in foods when food isnt 'chocolate')`.